# Base de Datos en Access direccionar ruta para exportar consultas a excel

Tags: ms-access, rutas

Tengo una Base de Datos en `MS Access 2016` con una Ruta para exportar Consultas a Excel.  Sin embargo, a veces debo trabajar en otras computadoras, por ello, necesito definir una Ruta permanente para mi Base de Datos.

En las lineas de codigo abajo indicadas la primera ruta funciona bien, pero la segunda muestra

> ERROR 3044 "...\CurrentProject.Path..." no es ruta de acceso válida.

En la web no he encontrado como escribir el segundo código correctamente. Agradezco su ayuda.

Primera Ruta de Código funciona bien.

```
sExcelWB = "D:\testing\" & Replace(Me.txttask_from, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_to, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_plot, "/", "_") & "_qry_task.xls"
```

Segunda Ruta de Código muestra `Error 3044`

```
sExcelWB = "CurrentProject.Path\" & Replace(Me.txttask_from, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_to, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_plot, "/", "_") & "_qry_task.xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

Si hablas de ruta de ubicación de los archivos debes establecerla de manera relativa.

Ejemplos de ubicación:

Absoluta: C:\Usuario\Desktop\carpeta_con_programa\carpeta_de_archivos\archivo.txt

Relativa:carpeta_de_archivos\archivo.txt

Estas dos funcionaran igual pero si cambias la carpeta del programa a otra pc solo funcionara la relativa.

Explico el ejemplo, en la ubicacion absoluta aparece el nombre de disco duro y se usuario, etc. Cosas que generalmente cambian entre cada pc por lo que la ubicación absoluta o ubicación completa no funcionara en otra pc. En cambio la posición relativa empieza a buscar desde el lugar donde se encuentra el programa por lo que si el archivo esta en una carpeta dentro de la solución('carpeta') principal de tu programa solo debes poner el nombre de la carpeta que contiene el archivo y luego el nombre del archivo('carpeta_de_archivos\archivo.txt').

Si la carpeta del archivo no esta dentro de la solución del programa puedes utilizar la ubicación relativa con la regla de los dos puntos:

Ejemplo de un archivo dentro de una carpeta que se encuentra en el escritorio al igual que el programa, como en este caso la carpeta del archivo no esta dentro de la del programa no podemos acceder a ella solo poniendo el nombre sino que debemos de salir de la carpeta del programa y luego entrar en la carpeta de los archivos.

Ejemplo:

Ubicaciones completas:

Programa: c:\user\Desktop\carpeta_programa\programa.exe

Archivo de referencia: c:\Desktop\carpeta_de_archivos\archivo.txt

Esta son las ubicaciones que no funcionarían en otra PC.

Ubicaciones relativas:
Para hacer referencia al archivo de referencia solo debes hacer lo siguiente:
..\carpeta_de_archivos\archivo.txt

Si lo notas los dos puntos regresan al contenedor o carpeta padre es decir el escritorio donde se encuentra la carpeta del programa y la carpeta de archivos por lo que con dos puntos al principio de nuestra cadena le indicamos que regrese a atrás a la carpeta padre y luego entre a la carpeta de archivos y encuentre el archivo.txt .

Espero que te sirva esta documentación.
[Ruta de archivos](https://www.google.com.do/amp/s/www.discoduroderoer.es/rutas-relativas-y-absolutas/amp/)

**Explicación Sencilla:**
Ejemplo:
Tienes tu programa en el escritorio dentro de una carpeta llamada *carpeta_programa* dentro de ella se encuentra tu programa *programa.exe*.

Además tienes los archivos de excel en una carpeta que esta en el escritorio con el nombre de *carpeta_excel* dentro de ella tienes tu archivo excel llamado *excel.xlsx*.

Si quieres que tu programa funcione en cualquier computadora cuando pongas la dirección de tu archivo en programación utilizas la forma relativa. En este caso sería:

```
..\carpeta_excel\excel.xls
```

Y tu programa funcionara con esa ruta en cualquier computadora que utilices el programa.

El porqué esta en la otra sección de la respuesta.

Comment: Recuerda en las ubicaciones relativas no debes poner c:

Comment: ¿En cual lenguaje programas?

Comment: Y porque usas replace, ¿que quieres hacer con eso?

Answer (score 0):

en el escritorio la carpeta BDR y escribí el siguiente código con la ruta relativa:

```
sExcelWB = "C:\CurrentProject.Path\BDR\" & Replace(Me.txttask_from, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_to, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_plot, "/", "_") & "_qry_task.xls"
```

Sin embargo, esta vez muestra el Error 3041 en la línea de código:

```
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
```

A pesar de mucho intentos, no he podido corregir dicho Error, por ello, aprecio la orientación que me puedan sugerir.

Comment: Denifer Santiago Fernandez. Agradezco sus preguntas.

Entonces ¿qué escribo en lugar de C:?
Programo en MS Access con Visual Basic Application.
Uso replace para programar el nombre de cada archvio exportado a Excel.
Tengo un formulario con tres txtboxes para buscar entre fechas y un valor. El archivo exportado tendra en el nombre la fechainicial&fechafinal&valor del código &nombre de la consulta.

Comment: Denifer.
Finalmente, hallé la línea de código para la Ruta Relativa. Este es el código:
sExcelWB = CurrentProject.Path & "\& ....xls"

Comment: Hola. Finalmente escribí la Ruta: sExcelWB = CurrentProject.Path\BDR\" & Replace(Me.txttask_from, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_to, "/", "_") & " - " & Replace(Me.txttask_plot, "/", "_") & "_qry_task.xls"

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo lo que entendí acerca de los puntos (..) para la Ruta Relativa intenté -sin éxito- las siguientes combinaciones:

```
"C:\..\BDR\" &
"C:..\BDR\" &
"C:\Escritorio..\BDR\" &
"C:\Escritorio\..\BDR\" &
```

Entonces, cada vez que use otra computadora me obliga a abrir el código para cambiar la ruta.
Por lo anterior, agradezco su ayuda para corregir mi error en la Ruta Relativa.

Comment: Denifer. Entonces que escribo en lugar de C: