# Como puedo hacer una ruta dinámica para subir una imagen en java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
String archivourl = "C:\\Users\\MAURICIO\\Desktop\\Helartico\\web\\imagenes";

DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

factory.setSizeThreshold(1024);

factory.setRepository(new File(archivourl));

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

try {

    List<FileItem> partes = upload.parseRequest(request);

    for (FileItem items : partes) {
        File file = new File(archivourl, items.getName());
        items.write(file);
```

Comment: Bro, deberias ser algo mas explicito o claro en espcificar que quieres y como lo quieres,  ademas, el codigo que tienes que error te genera ?

Comment: no genera un error, lo que quiero hacer es que si paso mi aplicacion a otro equipo no tenga que cambiar la ruta, si no que en ves de eso tome la ruta del equipo en que se encuentra, ese codigo la ruta esta estatica, es decir cada ves que cambio de equipo debo ir a esa variable y colocar la ruta del actual equipo

Comment: He respondido una pregunta similar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188067/base-de-datos-en-access-direccionar-ruta-para-exportar-consultas-a-excel/188100#188100

Answer (score 0):

Lo más normal es que saques la ruta del código (de hecho, cualquier ruta en el código huele muy mal) y la configures externamente.

Por ejemplo, si usas una base de datos puedes crear una tabla de configuración y guardar allí diferentes valores configurables. También puedes usar las propiedades del sistema (`System.getProperty`), JNDI si el servidor lo soporta, etc...

Java Servlet tiene un mecanismo específico definido para configuración; se trata del elemento `context-param` dentro del fichero `web.xml`. Dentro de este puedes escribir:

```
<web-app>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>archivourl</param-name>
    <param-value>C:\miRuta</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ...
</web-app>
```

Y dentro de un servlet o jsp haces:

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("archivourl");
```

para recuperar el valor.